# Duplicate contacts report

Tags: reporting, duplicate-management

I've been trying to figure out the best way to design a **report to browse duplicate contacts**, but I can't seem to find a solution I like.

One of the solutions I found is using the famous **[Power of One](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063000000048RbAAI)** where you create a formula field in the contact with a default value of one to later summarize in the report. The problem with this solution is that **I haven't managed to filter out the "sumarizations" that are lower than 2**.

I have also figured out other solutions including code in order to mark records as duplicates, etc. but **I'm interested in finding a purely declarative way.** Is it possible?

I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: What is your definition of duplicate contact, i.e. what fields are involved?

Comment: @DavidCheng , it doesn't matter, suppose email and Last Name :)